# Whenever I upload onto an existing repository, a github error 'repository not found' prevents me from doing it

Tags: git, github, repository

I tried to create a repository wherein I can organize all my projects. However, I had trouble committing my existing folders onto it (essentially, when I committed folders that I had on my computer, I was unable to open the folders and access its contents). After a few hours of attempts & research, I decided to just delete it & solve that problem for another day.

Unfortunately, now that I am trying to push commits to other existing repos, I am coming across this error when I enter 'git push origin master'.

> remote: Repository not found.

fatal: repository 'my deleted github repo' not found

How do I push my commit onto the existing repo that I did not delete and still exists on my account?

Comment: What does `git remote -v` give? Is the url of the remote repository correct?

Comment: @GoodDeeds No it doesn't give the correct url of the remote repository. I'm not entirely certain how to change it.

Comment: Set it using `git remote set-url origin <url>`.

Comment: I did that and tried pushing again but I came across this error: " ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/url'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details."

 I'm guessing it's because I uploaded some commits manually instead of doing it via command prompt?

Comment: Yes, not because of manual upload, but because your branches are not longer in sync. You need `git pull` first.

Comment: I tried that but it just says From https://github.com/XXX/Analyze-AB-Test-Results
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories